# Cannot Match A X.509 CN With A Java Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use a Regular Expression to match a CN from an X.509 certificate.

The entire string will look something like this:

CN=JASON, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG

Here's the nonworking code:

```
    Object certChain = request
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
    String name = "";
    if (certChain != null) {
        X509Certificate certs[] = (X509Certificate[]) certChain;
        X509Certificate cert = certs[0];
        name = cert.getSubjectDN().getName();
    }

    String strPattern = "CN=(.*?),";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(strPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
    String cname = "";
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        cname = matcher.group(1);
    }
```

Matcher.matches() returns false, but I don't see a problem with the pattern. Can anyone help?

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the string fully in `Matcher.matches()`, you could use:

```
String strPattern = "CN=(.*?),.*";
```

Comment: That seems to have done it. It's weird because I copied the same pattern used by Spring Security (which I just can't use in this one area).

Answer (score 4):

The `Matcher.matches` only returns true if the pattern matches *all* of the input. You have two paths forward:

- Expand the pattern to match all of the input: `"CN=(.*?),.*"`
- Use `Matcher.find` to find the first occurrence of the pattern in the input. Subsequent calls to find will match successive occurrences in the input.